# Couldn't get any accounts!, Ethereum client is not configured correctly

Tags: web3js, truffle, blockchain, metamask, ganache-cli

I'm running testrpc on the default port 7545.

I run truffle console and test with: `web3.eth.getAccounts().then( function (result) { return result[0] });`

This works fine. According to docs the getAccounts() method only works if the account is connected properly with ganache, so it seems I should be all set.

when I enable MetaMask in crome and setup to required accounts, localhost web page is showing loading evin i had properly setup MetaMask as shown in image.

[image: Capture333]
But when I dissabled the MetaMask, It is showing proper output with account at index 0 as shown below:
[image: Capture444]

```
truffle version
Truffle v5.1.26 (core: 5.1.26)
Solidity - 0.4.25 (solc-js)
Node v12.13.0
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

Please help me getting out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display accounts with Metamask first you have to prompt the user to allow the application to have access to the accounts.

Check https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1102.md

Look for `window.ethereum` and if it's presented call `window.ethereum.enable()` and after that is resolved, you will be able to access the accounts.

Comment: Do we have to look for `window.ethereum` in truffle console?

Comment: I cannot answer you precisely to that question because I haven't used truffle. You have to ask about that in the code that is executed in the browser.

Comment: thanks Tek let me check for that

Comment: `let app = await Election.deployed()`  , `let accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts()` and `app.vote(1,{ from: accounts[1] })`  is working in truffle that means i can vote from different accounts, so I'm having account access

Comment: so there is no need for `window.ethereum.enable()`

Comment: EIP1102 wasn't implemented by all providers but for sure it was implemented by  Metamask. 
If you want to have access to the accounts in MM , you have to do it that way.